# How to explicitly configure EF Core (+MySql) to map GUID to CHAR(36)?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, guid

Getting error on migration starting :
The property 'Post.Id' is of type 'Guid' which is not supported by current database provider.

```
[Column("id", TypeName = "Char(36)")]
public Guid Id
```